# 'Bye' Vs 'Good Bye'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, greetings

I have read/heard at many places where **Goodbye** is **not** ***good***. It is a **final remark** on that very harsh moment.

Scene #1: Mike and Sarah are in good relationship.

> *"Hey honey, see you tomorrow. **Bye!**"*

Scene #2: Mike and Sarah are now about to *break up.*

> *"I don't want to see you anymore. **Goodbye!**"*

You get an idea? The given example is in the context of a *relationship* but it can be anything. Say friends getting angry at each other and decide not to talk forever. Earlier, they used **bye** and now, there is ***final*** **goodbye**.

In simple words, is **goodbye** a ***final*** **bye**?

Comment: I would consider any form of *bye* simply as parting, not an implication of anything *good*. I would say *goodbye* is more formal than *bye* but otherwise interchangeable.

Comment: You may be reading a bit too much into it - to me, the two are absolutely equivalent, both connotatively and denotatively.

Comment: Not just *reading*. I observe/hear that as well. @AlexK Maybe, it's like ['god bless you'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71539/if-god-bless-someone-something-is-it-positive-or-negative-same-with-all-the) in a different tone?

Comment: @MaulikV I didn't mean it in a bad way - just as a passing comment. Maybe it's like god bless you in that regard, but I personally find no difference between the two. Let me phrase this more concretely...To me, there is NO difference between. "Hey honey, see you tomorrow. Bye!" and "Hey honey, see you tomorrow. Good bye!" I prefer "Good bye" for more dramatic situations that are negative, but the words can be used interchangeably in the sentence without changing the connotation surrounding that sentence. This is all in my experience, just commenting....

Comment: I did not take it in any other way. I thought that I should clarify it further. Even in some movies I've heard 'more use of' goodbye as a final 'bye'.

Comment: @MaulikV To me, it can be used in a more dramatic setting (it's two words vs. one word), but it doesn't necessarily carry a dramatic connotation with it. In other words, a friend won't think that something is wrong if you choose to say "Goodbye" instead of "bye."

Comment: These days, *goodbye* is usually written as one word.  See Google Books Ngram Viewer: https://goo.gl/RI8Mbh

Comment: I feel like goodbye is more serious. Like if someone told me "goodbye", it feels somewhat more permanent. Of course, it might just be the tone of voice commonly used with goodbye.

Comment: that's what exactly makes this question here @SenjougaharaHitagi

Answer (score 6):

*Goodbye* can be used as a final farewell when someone is ending a relationship or walking out on someone. It is a more formal word than *bye* and thus makes sense in this context. Also, when slamming the door and walking out on someone, a robust two-syllable *good**bye*** adds strength to the nonverbal cues.

But *bye*, because of its informality, can be used to express disinterest in someone. *Okay, bye, I don't even want to waste a second syllable on you.*

So it is not that either word is always worse than the other.

*Goodbye* is the customary leave taking and while friends may shorten that on a daily basis to other, less formal forms including *bye bye* (common in AmE), there is nothing inherently "not good" in the full form.

Answer (score 4):

**Good-bye**, or **Goodbye**, is a contraction of "**God be with ye**."

"Bye," "Bye now," "Bye-bye" are all contractions of the contraction. Nothing wrong with any of them.

Answer (score 1):

**Goodbye** is a formal **send-off** when parting company. It is an evolved form of :

> **God be with you**.

In the same way that **farewell** is to :

> **Fare thee well**.

Both **goodbye** and **farewell** can have the connotation of **finality** in a way that no other **send-off**s have :

> They said their **last goodbyes** before he died.
>   When she said, "**Goodbye.**", he knew it was over.
>   They had waved their **final farewells** to the ill fated mission on that morning.

but this is not necessarily the case.  Probably one of the most famous "**goodbyes**" was that heard by millions of subscribers to AOL when **logging off**, and it is hard to imagine AOL not wanting to see their customers again.

**Goodbye** is also the term used to signify **companies parting** :

> *( at this point David and Marie say their* ***goodbyes*** *)*
>   David: **Bye** Marie, see you tomorrow
>   Marie: **Ciao**